# import math outputting wrong answer

Tags: python

Import Math's trigonometry functions don't output the correct result.

```
print(math.tan(math.degrees(60)))
```

outputs 1.1255751154673213.

On my calculator (deg), it outputs 1.73205080757

Anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 6):

To convert from degrees to radians you need [`math.radians()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians), not [`math.degrees()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.degrees)